# Can I bake my bread in a loaf pan instead of baking sheet?

Tags: bread

I have found a lot of recipes that says to bake your bread on a cookie sheet. I was wondering if I can use a loaf pan instead? Do you have to adjust time or any thing else? My family like sandwich style bread better than French style. Most of the recipes are sourdough some are French bread.

Comment: You always *can*, but just expect some level of variation. In this case, the shape is an obvious change, but you also might bake longer than expected if you don't immediately pop the loaf out of the pan after removing it from the oven.

Comment: "Sandwich style" doesn't just mean that it was made in a loaf... If that's all you're concerned with, go for it... but I'd be concerned that you'll be unhappy with the crust. Putting it in a pan won't make it have the nice, soft texture and crust that you see in standard American white loaves.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a thermometer and bake to an internal temperature of 190F (88C) ...or 200F (93C) if the dough is enriched with butter, eggs or milk.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, always good to have a second opinion. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I do this all the time. You can keep a soft crust by doing 1 of 2 things - a pan/bowl of water in the oven (lowest shelf possible) the last 5/10 minutes of baking OR once the bread is out of the pan (immediately after removal from oven), lay a moist towel (paper towel works best as there no weight) over the loaf as it cools.
Note: this is what I have done for years, have no idea how well it will work for someone else.